# where is the udp_deliver api in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, rtos

I tried to find the above api in linux kerenl. If I go to this path:  net/ipv4/udp.c and search for udp_deliver. It is not there at that place. What is the reason for not finding the udp_deliver api ??
please someone help me. I dont have the above api in the above specified path.

PLEASE

Comment: please someone reply.

Answer (score 0):

I just cloned the mainline `linux` repo to find the definition of `udp_deliver`. I do not believe that function is implemented any more in the kernel, as using `grep` does not yield any hits.

```
$ grep -r udp_deliver linux
$ grep -r *udp_deliver* linux
```

They both yield nothing. I can only find reference to `udp_deliver` in early versions of the Linux kernel, namely [1.0.13](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/SO/Linux/Kod/net/ipv4/udp.cc.html), [1.1.72](http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-1.1.72/R/10826.html), [1.3.22](http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-1.3.22/R/16544.html), [1.3.47](http://kernelhistory.sourcentral.org/linux-1.3.47/R/19560.html) and some other early versions.

The [definition given](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/SO/Linux/Kod/net/ipv4/udp.cc.html) in these early source files is as follows:

```
static inline void udp_deliver(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    skb->sk = sk;

    if (sk->users) {
        __skb_queue_tail(&sk->back_log, skb);
        return;
    }
    udp_queue_rcv_skb(sk, skb);
}
```

Comment: udp_deliver is same as udp_recv ??